# Python+Tkinter, how to run in background independant of tk frontend?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I'm a tkinter noob.

What would be the preferred way to run a long-running process in the background, separate from my tkinter popup(form?)?

I've read different things about multithreading while using tkinter and can't find a straightforward "do it like this".

To be clear, the behavior I need is, user starts program, tkinter bit pops up saying the process has started. User can dismiss this popup without affecting the rest of the processes. Maybe when the process has finished I can throw up another tkinter popup.

If tkinter is overkill for this, please feel free to suggest a better approach.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Joran Beasley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541038/joran-beasley) has the right [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42589579/9647762), but way over-complicated things.

Here's the simple version:

```
class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        # long process goes here

w = Worker()
w.start()
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Work Started", "OK started working")
w.join()
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Work Complete", "OK Done")
```

Edit: here's a working example of it:

```
import threading
import time
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        # long process goes here
        time.sleep(10)

w = Worker()
w.start()
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Work Started", "OK started working")
root.update()
w.join()
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Work Complete", "OK Done")
```

Answer (score 1):

theading is simpler since you can share object state

```
class Worker:
    finished = False
    def do_work(self):
       os.system("...")
       self.finished=True
    def start(self):
        self.th = threading.Thread(target=self.do_work)
        self.th.start()

w = Worker()
w.start()
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Work Started", "OK started working")
while not w.finished:
    time.sleep(0.5)
tkMessageBox.showinfo("Work Complete", "OK Done")
```

Comment: while condition: sleep is pretty much an anti pattern. Condition variables exist for a reason although in this case join would do just as well (and in a larger gui program you'd want to marshal to the gui thread)

Comment: good point .... im often waiting on some state variable that im polling for status of my task... this is overkill to just wait for it to exit... i was clearly not thinking :P