# Blank Tkinter window when executing the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm coding a tkinter programm which sorts the random numbers with different sorting algorithms. You have to insert the range of numbers to sort, then you press enter and it shows you the unsorted numbers on the right, after you choose a sorting algorithm and press sort and it prints out the sorted numbers on the right. But my problem is, that after I execute the programm, the tinker window is just blank. I'm still a beginner.

```
import random

try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

MAX = 999

MIN = 0

class Application(Frame):


def __init__(self, master):

    Frame.__init__(self, master)
    master.minsize(width=600, height=400)
    self.grid()

def create_widgets(self):

    Label(self,
          text="Dieses Programm sortiert die angegebene Anzahl von Zahlen nach einem Sortierverfahren."
          ).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    Label(self,
          text="Wie viele Zahlen wollen Sie sortieren?"
          ).grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    Label(self,
          text="Hier sind die sortierten Zahlen"
          ).grid(row=0, column=4, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    Label(self,
          text="Welches Sortierverfahren wollen sie nutzen?"
          ).grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W)

    self.anzahl_ent=Entry(self)
    self.anzahl_ent.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)

    Button(self,
           text="Eingabe",
           command=self.get_anzahl
           ).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)

    self.v=IntVar()

    Radiobutton(self,
                text="Bubblesort",
                variable=v,
                value=1
                ).grid(row=5,column=1, sticky=W)

    Radiobutton(self,
                text="Quicksort",
                variable=v,
                value=2
                ).grid(row=6, column=1, sticky=W)

    Button(self,
           text="SORTIEREN",
           command=self.Zahlsortieren
           ).grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=W)


    self.sortierteZahlen_txt = Text(self, width=50, heigh=200)
    self.sortierteZahlen_txt.grid(row=2, column=4, sticky=W)





def get_anzahl(self):

        self.anzahl=int(self.anzahl_ent.get())
        self.ranZahlen()



def ranZahlen(self):

        self.liste = [random.randrange(MIN, MAX) for _ in xrange(anzahl)]
        self.zahlen_ausgeben(self.liste)


def Zahlsortieren(self):
    if v==2:
        def partition(arr, low, high):
            i = (low - 1)
            pivot = arr[high]

            for j in range(low, high):

                if arr[j] <= pivot:
                    i = i + 1
                    arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]

            arr[i + 1], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[i + 1]
            return (i + 1)


        def quickSort(arr, low, high):
            if low < high:

                pi = partition(arr, low, high)


                quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1)
                quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high)

        n = len(liste)
        quickSort(liste, 0, n - 1)
        for i in range(n):
            self.zahlenliste1=print("%d" % liste[i])

        self.zahlen_ausgeben(self.zahlenliste1)
        return

    elif v==1:
        def bubbleSort(arr):
            n = len(arr)

            for i in range(n):


                for j in range(0, n - i - 1):

                    # traverse the array from 0 to n-i-1
                    # Swap if the element found is greater
                    # than the next element
                    if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]:
                        arr[j], arr[j + 1] = arr[j + 1], arr[j]



        bubbleSort(liste)

        for i in range(len(liste)):
            self.zahlenliste2=print("%d" % liste[i])

        self.zahlen_ausgeben(self.zahlenliste2)

        return


def zahlen_ausgeben(self, message):

        self.sortierteZahlen_txt.delete(0.0, END)
        self.sortierteZahlen_txt.insert(0.0, message)


def main():
    root=Tk()
    root.title("Sortierverfahren")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

main()
```

Comment: You never call create_widgets.

Comment: @MennoHölscher so I have to call it after self.grid() right?

Comment: Yes, good place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `create_widgets` in order to display anything. Change your main method to be:

```
def main():
    root=Tk()
    root.title("Sortierverfahren")
    app = Application(root)
    app.create_widgets()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your calls to `quickSort` or `bubbleSort` are blocking. Take a look at this question to see how to dispatch background jobs that don't block the UI:

[Python+Tkinter, how to run in background independant of tk frontend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42589372/pythontkinter-how-to-run-in-background-independant-of-tk-frontend)