# How to block taskmgr.exe from starting?

Tags: python

I'm writing a program in python that will use 2-Factor authentication to unlock user workspace. It can't be closed with alt+F4, and I'm using root.overrideredirect() to remove all close, minimize, etc. buttons.
but it can be escaped with Alt+Tab and Ctrl-Shift-Esc. Alt-Tab can't be fixed but I want to kill task manager as it starts. I tried writing module for that but it stuck on while loop of kill taskmgr program.
I cant do root.mainloop().

module for kill:

```
import os
import elevate
elevate.elevate()
while True:
    os.system("taskkill /f /IM taskmgr.exe")
```

Comment: you are doing it backwards ... disallow the execution of taskmgr.exe at system level ... use password to allow execution

Comment: but I want my code work on any computer

Comment: `while True` is going to block your main thread, execute it in a background thread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python+Tkinter, how to run in background independant of tk frontend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42589372/pythontkinter-how-to-run-in-background-independant-of-tk-frontend)

Comment: @SsNipeR1 what problem are you trying to solve? .... what would prevent someone from stopping python